# How to remove an apostrophe and a space from my string (AS3 Flash CC possibly regex)?

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, escaping, flash-cs6

I have a string that goes in a textfield. This string comes from an xml-file.
This string is also the name of an mp3 I call when people click on the textfield.

The strings are in Dutch (because it's for a Dutch program) and my language has certain words that are written like this: **'s nachts**.
So you have an *apostrophe*, an *s*, a *space* and a *word* (basically it means *at night*).

Because you can't have audiofiles starting with an apostrophe, I would like to convert the string **'s nachts** to **snachts**. That way I can call on **snachts.mp3**.

I would love to be able to regex this, but I don't know enough about it to do so.

Comment: Isn't a simple string replace enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something this simple, you probably don't need to use a regular expression. Something like this should work:

```
myString = myString.replace("'s ", "s");
```

Of course it *could* be a regular expression, like this:

```
myString = myString.replace(/'s /g, "s");
```

Comment: ah yes THANK YOU this is exactly what I need right now. I might have to refine it in the future ... and this is so simple I'm quite miffed I didn't think of it myself :s

Comment: what does the /g mean in the regex?

Comment: @silvith it's the 'global' flag. It means 'replace all'.

Comment: @silvith like said above, it's a global flag. If you do not add this, it will only replace the first match.

Comment: @djib I opted for the string-replace. I'll need the regex in the future when the script needs to be done well, but this was only a quick fix. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove any letter that is not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _

```
myString = myString.replace(/\W/g, '');
```